# jQuery selected grid cell not returning html() value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a dynamically-created ASP.net gridview. I want to return the contents of the grid cell my user clicks. Everywhere I look, the html() property should do it, but mine keeps coming back 'undefined'.

I'm set up so only the first column responds to clicks. My code:

```
$('#dgrMainGrid td:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
    var barCode = $('this').html();
    alert(barCode);
 })
```

I've tried a few hail-Marys based on advice from various sites, but the consensus is that html() should work. I'm wondering if the way I select my cell is wrong - in other words, my 'this' isn't what I think it is.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is a rendered HTML row.

```
</tr><tr>
    <td>TD-00154</td>
    <td>IV PRobe</td>
    <td>Romex</td>
    <td>350 Under</td> 
    <td>217M01866</td>
</tr><tr>
```

Comment: seeing the html would help... can you show us the generated html for the gridview?

Comment: `$(this)` not `$('this')`

Comment: what criss said. also, try with $(document).on("click",''#dgrMainGrid td:nth-child(1)", function(){
var barCode = $(this).html();
});

Comment: DAG NABBIT! I stared at this idiotic mistake for 45 minutes. Sorry, wasting everybody's time. Thanks to responders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is not good I think, it must be `$(this).html()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling your JS after the DOM (document object model) has been loaded or mostly you will get `undefined` when selecting the `dgrMainGrid`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // add your code hear
});
```

Also, when calling ASP.net `GridView` by ID use `<%= dgrMainGrid.ClientID %>` instide of `dgrMainGrid` as ID is auto generated in HTML.